# ITLB vs. a regular TLB

Tags: cpu, translation, buffer

What is the difference between an ITLB and a TLB?

Comment: Have you considered, you know, googling? It's in the references to the TLB wikipedia article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ITLB (Instruction Translation Lookaside Buffer) only handles instructions, while a TLB handles both instructions and data. There could also be a DTLB, handling only data.

Comment: I looked up DTLB and it says that the D stands for dual, not data.

Comment: @OSXJedi Hard to believe in the context of contrasting it to ITLB. THe first few Google hits for "DTLB" also seem to side with "Data". I guess in that case it was probably standing alone. There are only so many letters in the alphabet.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=dtlb&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g9&aql=&oq= The first link goes to the Wikipedia article, but the 2nd and 3rd links go to sites that interpret the D as "Dual."

Comment: @OSXJedi You get different results than me. Doesn't change what I wrote. If it's in the context of contrasting DTLB and ITLB, it's clearly *Data*. Also, you never even asked about it. Why are you so hung up about some bonus info I provided with answering your question?